# iOS simulator window height difference between 7.1 and 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, constraints

I didn't find any solution for my problem anywhere in Stack Overflow or other sites. So here is the problem:

I am developing an iOS Universal app, portrait orientation only. When I run it on iOS 8.3 simulator window and all other views layout seems to be normal.

But when I run the same app on iOS 7.1 simulator, which I downloaded from developer's site for Xcode 6, the window height seems to be approximately 100 px smaller.

I checked the couple of view frames for both simulators.

- 7.1 simulator was returning width = 320, height = 480
- 8.3 simulator returned width = 320, height = 568

I am using storyboard and constraints.

I am pretty sure that a lot of people had this problem, so I am hoping to hear some useful advices from you.
Check out the screenshots below:

[image: Here is the view for 8.3 simulator]
[image]

Comment: Just add launch screens in your project. You will get desired output.

Comment: @AshishKakkad I am using LauncScreen.xib in my project, do I also need to add Splashscreens for 7.1 devices? I will try that, but don't understand how that helps.

Comment: I think the 7.1 will not support LauncScreen.xib

Comment: @AshishKakkad The answer should be placed in an answer box and not edited into the question. This is how you gain reputation, if Aza or Ashish don't put it there it will be made into a community wiki for you.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 Brother I have not edited the answer. I just maid the comment. Thanks I will add the answer for it.

Comment: You should not be doing anything that depends on the screen dimensions. It is bad.

Comment: @Fogmeister I actually don't. I just couldn't figure out why simulator window heights were different, that's why I captured view frame bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added Answer as per [Brian Tompsett - 汤莱恩](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4370109/brian-tompsett-%E6%B1%A4%E8%8E%B1%E6%81%A9)'s Suggestion.
Solution is already done on comments.

---

iOS 7.x does not support LaunchScreen.xib

So, Manually add the LaunchScreens in the assets folder and you will get desired output.

- Go to Project settings --> Target --> App Icons and Launch Images
- Launch Image Source was empty so, open it and chose to Migrate from Images.

So now window height is back to 568 on iOS 7.1 simulator